# SQL query to aggregate data based on months (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

The table that I querying is :

table testing_table:

```
testType | period_from | period_to| copies |
       1 |     20180101|  20181201|       1|
       2 |    20180101 |  20191201|       1|
       3 |     20190101|  20191201|       1|
```

---

I want to loop through the array and use the below query to generate values like this:

```
DateVar | ABTEST | CDTEST | EFTEST |
20180101|       4|       0|       0|
20180201|       3|       4|       2|
```

---

dateVar = ['20180101','20180201','20180501'].

I am trying to develop an sql query like this:

```
SELECT
     SUM (
     CASE
     WHEN (testType = 1 AND (period_from <= dateVar AND period_to >= dateVar)) THEN
     copies
     ELSE
     0
     END
     ) AS "ABTEST",
     SUM (
     CASE
     WHEN (testType = 2 AND (period_from <= dateVar AND period_to >= dateVar)) THEN
     copies
     ELSE
     0
     END
     ) AS "CDTEST",
     SUM (
     CASE
     WHEN (testType = 3 AND (period_from <= dateVar AND period_to >= dateVar)) THEN
     copies
     ELSE
     0
     END
     ) AS "EFTEST"
    FROM
     testing_table;
```

I am lost as to what to do with it. Do I look into functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use unnest function to accomplish what you are asking i have written a query you may want to check

```
SELECT DTVAR, 
            SUM(CASE 
            WHEN TestType = 1
                THEN copies
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'ABTEST', 
            SUM(CASE 
            WHEN TestType = 2
                THEN copies
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'CDTEST', 
            SUM(CASE 
            WHEN TestType = 3
                THEN copies
            ELSE 0
            END) AS 'EFTEST'
FROM (
    SELECT DTVAR, TestType, sum(copies) AS copies
    FROM testing_table
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DTVAR
        FROM unnest(dateVar ['20180101','20180201','20180501']) AS DTVAR
        ) AA
        ON (
                period_from <= DTVAR
                AND period_to >= DTVAR
                )
    GROUP BY DTVAR, TestType
    ) A
GROUP BY DTVAR
```

hope this helps..